# Boundary value problem $u'(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, boundary-value-problem

For this problem:
[image]

We have this graph:[image]

What I am confused is what should $u'(0)$ and $u'(1)$ be?

**1) For $u'(0)$ , the solution is $u'(0) = \frac{u_2-u_1}{\Delta x}$ , but why is it not $u'(0) = \frac{u_1-u_0}{\Delta x}$???**

**2) Same thing as $u'(1)$ , the solution is $u'(1) = \frac{u_4-u_3}{\Delta x}$ , but why is it not $u'(0) = \frac{u_5-u_4}{\Delta x}$???**

Comment: The problem **tells** you that the u values corresponding to $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ are $u_0$, $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$.  There is **no** "$u_0$".

Comment: @user247327 yea i understand, but even though the problem doesn't have $u_0$, it doesn't mean that we cannot assume there's a u_0... What I am more concerned is how to get the $u'(0)$....

Comment: To evaluate $u'(0)$ one must see how the function behave next to the point $x=0$,in this case $x_1=0$ and as the image says $u(0)=u(x_1)=u_1$,now we take the next point that is $x_2$ as there is nothing on the left of zero,so the expression we obtain is the doubtful,yet true,$u'(0) = \frac{u_2-u_1}{\Delta x}$. As for the second question,your function $u'$ may not be defined when $x>1=x_4$ so you have to approach $x_4$ by the left side. I hope it helps to clarify.